# How can I make jQuery slide function stop moving my other div elements?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have four divs that have unordered lists in them. They unordered lists are set to `display: none`, so when I hover over the parent divs, the lists slide down (using jQuery's `slideToggle()`).

This is all working fine except for the issue where the other three divs are being pushed down by the slide function. I want all the divs to stay in their place when the list slides out.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#school").hover(function() {
    $("#schoolList").slideToggle("fast");
  });
  $("#entertainment").hover(function() {
    $("#entertainmentList").slideToggle("fast");
  });
  $("#programming").hover(function() {
    $("#programmingList").slideToggle("fast");
  });
  $("#projects").hover(function() {
    $("#projectList").slideToggle("fast");
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #53a8ed;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#title {
  margin: 0 auto;
  line-height: 150px;
  font-size: 48px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #0c5591;
}

.contentHeader {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.category {
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0 2%;
  background-color: #0c5591;
  display: inline-block;
}

#content {
  margin-top: 175px;
  text-align: center;
}

.list {
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
  /* margin-left: -12%; */
  font-size: large;
  line-height: 50px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  color: white;
}

a:hover {
  color: #9ad0fc;
}

#googleSearch {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -375px;
  top: 27.5%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#searchBar {
  width: 700px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 25px 0 0 25px;
  ;
  border: none;
  flex-grow: 2;
}

#searchBar:focus {
  outline: none;
}

#searchBar[type=text] {
  padding-left: 15px;
  font-family: 'Dosis';
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

#goButton {
  width: 50px;
  border: none;
  background: #0c5591;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 0 25px 25px 0;
  font-family: 'Dosis';
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<h1 id="title">Home</h1>
<form id="googleSearch" action="https://www.google.com/search" method="GET">
  <input id="searchBar" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search">
  <button id="goButton" type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
<div id="content">
  <div id="school" class="category">
    <h3 class="contentHeader">School</h3>
    <ul id="schoolList" class="list">
      <li><a href="https://app.schoology.com/home">Schoology</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive">Google Drive</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://plusportals.com/gmhs">Plus Portals</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/research_and_citation/mla_style/mla_formatting_and_style_guide/mla_formatting_and_style_guide.html">MLA
                            Citation</a></li>
    </ul id="schoolList" class="list">
  </div>
  <div id="entertainment" class="category">
    <h3 class="contentHeader">Entertainment</h3>
    <ul id="entertainmentList" class="list">
      <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/">Youtube</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.netflix.com">Netflix</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="programming" class="category">
    <h3 class="contentHeader">Programming</h3>
    <ul id="programmingList" class="list">
      <li><a href="">cPanel</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">NameCheap</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Github</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Khan
                            Academy</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.udemy.com/home/my-courses/learning/">uDemy</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.mediacollege.com/linux/command/linux-command.html">Linux Commands</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="projects" class="category">
    <h3 class="contentHeader">Projects</h3>
    <ul id="projectList" class="list">
      <li><a href="chrome://extensions/">Extensions</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.grahambillington.com/pong">Pong</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by adding a vertical alignment to the parent div:

```
.category {
   width: 250px;
   margin: 0 2%;
   background-color: #0c5591;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

This aligns all of the divs relative to the top side of the other surrounding divs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the container . By changing the display to "inline-grid" the div will behave nicer. However, you will still not have it the way you want. My best guess is because of the "position" of the  element. You can either get away with it by managing the containing elements with "position: absolute" or by creating a list view rather than columns and rows.

```
.category {
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0 2%;
  background-color: #0c5591;
  display: inline-grid;
}
```